# errors when click create button on output event adaptor in WSO2 CEP 3.1

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

When I click *create new output event adaptor* get this error:

```
TID[-1234] [CEP] [2015-11-24 21:44:07,595] ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext} - JSPException while including path '/outputeventadaptormanager/create_eventAdaptor.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:102)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88) 
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75) 
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:607) 
    org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:339)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) 
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) 
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61) 
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) 
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetection
```

Everything works on Windows and list all output event adaptors which I created. But when I do the same on Linux it didn't show list of adaptors and show error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Youngoo,

WSO2 CEP 3.1.0 is well tested in Linux environments. Specially above scenario is a basic flow in CEP. Can you please let me know in which OS version, you observed above issue.. Are you using JDK 6 or 7 (Jdk 8 is not a supported jdk for CEP 3.1.0)